# Approximating a solution to a general cubic using a pertubative method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have

> $$ax^{1/2}+bx^{3/2}=c$$

if we assume there is no information about the relation between $a$ and $b$ (like one is small compared to the other), can anyone give me a good technique used to approximate the solution to leading order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, setting $y=x^{1/2}$ is indicated, then [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is your friend, though I am not sure what you mean by "to leading order".

Comment: OK, what is Newton's method called specifically so I can look it up?

Comment: Isn't it Newton-Raphson?

Comment: See the link, the both of you.

Comment: You want the link? You want the link? You can't handle the link. Forget it Marge, it's China town!

Comment: If you can handle it, it's there now.

Comment: what guess would you give for the initial step?

Comment: That very much depends. In principle, it should not matter, but since every cubic has a real root, you can get pretty close to it by bisection (it should be easy to find two points where the LHS - RHS have different signs).